# Is Using MVVM with SwiftUI a 'bad practice'?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I am writing a SwiftUI app and am having a hard time understanding the best architectural pattern to go with. I know MVVM is the go-to in mobile development in general, but have also seen sources that say that swiftUI has MVVM built in, so all that is needed is MV. Here is one such source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699003. This and many other articles say that using swiftUI with MVVM is redundant.

I've also seen other sources that say MVVM is just fine for swiftUI.

Is it just a matter of personal preference? Or, is explicitly defining viewmodels redundant in swiftUI?

Comment: Apple started to emphasize MVVM so people don't create a spaghetti code (i.e. everything is in one class). Where MVVM is needed, and where you need more patterns depends very much on the app. So far I have not seen an app that would just use MVVM. But I also didn't see an app where it would be a good idea to put network calls inside the view itself, like the article you linked implies. It looks good in primitive examples, not so good when you end up with thousands of lines mixing functionality and UI. Not to mention how untestable that code is.

Comment: MVVM is ok if it is needed and used appropriately, If you have one `ObservableObject` for several layers of `View`s you will end up encountering bugs such as "popping" links, closing sheets because things are redrawing.

Comment: SwiftUI is an architectural pattern already, it's based on ELM, you don't need another one. Also the View struct is a view model already you don't need another one, it is already a separation from the actual UIView objects it generates for you. The people teaching MVVM first on UIKit and now trying to also do it with SwiftUI have not realised this yet. The people teaching TCA don't realise SwiftUI already has a reducer built-in.

Comment: So what is the alternative @malhal? Do you just have a service class, or use interactors?

Comment: `@State` / `@Binding` for view data. `ObservableObject` for model data. This video explains it all https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040

Comment: @timbretimbre I was wondering if you have any links/sources to support that Apple emphasizes MVVM. Not trying to attack you or anything but it would be nice to know. Been researching this for a while